# Роутинг на Quasar-Framework автоматически

Tags: node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

Я думаю многие сталкивались с проблемой, когда в проекте [Quasar](https://qusar.dev) есть много файлов и страниц и каждый раз новую страницу приходится вручную прописывать в файл с маршрутами. При этом часто просто забываешь это сделать, что приводит к тому что при загрузке сайта видишь 404 ошибку.
Кроме того по сути это лишняя работа, так как этот процесс возможно автоматизировать.

В [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) например маршруты строятся автоматически, хотелось бы подобной функциональности и на Quasar.
Возможно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

В этой статье привожу метод, который позволит генерировать файл с маршрутами автоматически по структуре директорий проекта.

Наша задача: Найти все файлы *.vue в директории `/src/pages` и во всех её поддиректориях.
Мы напишем `NodeJs` скрипт, который строить файл с маршрутами автоматически по этой информации и сделаем авто-запуск этого скрипта при сборке проекта Quasar.

Рабочий скрипт может выглядеть примерно так:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');
const patternAll = 'src/**/*.@(js|vue)';
const componentsPaths = glob.sync("src/pages/**/*.vue");
console.log("Files: ", componentsPaths, "\n");
let items = "";
for(let path of componentsPaths) {
    let rpath = path.substring("src/pages/".length, path.length - 4);
    if(rpath.endsWith("Index")) 
        rpath = rpath.substring(0, rpath.length - "Index".length);
    else  if(rpath.endsWith("Error404"))
        continue;
    items += `        { path: '${rpath}', component: () => import(\'${path}\') },\n`;
}
const text = `
const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
      children: [
${items}
        ]
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
    }
  ]
  export default routes
  `
  console.log("autoRoutes.js: ", text);
  fs.writeFile('./src/router/autoRoutes.js', text, () => {
      console.log("All done!");
  })
```

Кладём наш скрипт в корневую директорию проекта c названием `makeAutoRoutes.js` и тестируем:
`node makeAutoRoutes`
В консоли мы должны увидеть листинг результирующего файла и надпись "All done!", так же должен создаться файл с кодов `/src/router/autoRoutes.js`, в котором и находятся все наши автоматически построенные маршруты.

Что бы подключить  этот файл в роутер, меняем в файле `/src/route/index.js` строку `import routes from './routes'` на `import routes from './autoRoutes'`.
С этого момент наш роутер будет работать с нашим новым файлом, который генерится автоматически.

Осталось прописать наш скрипт `makeAutoRoutes` на автозапуск при сборке проекта. Это делается очень легко:
Добавляем первой строчкой в файл `quasar.conf.js` строку `require('./makeAutoRoutes.js')`.

Теперь запускаем сборку Quasar `quasar build` или `quasar dev` и все файлы vue в папке `/src/pages` автоматически подключены как маршруты.

Наслаждаемся!

PS: После того как я проверил мой метод и написал эту статью, я узнал что такая функциональность уже планируется в Quasar, и более того уже в [процессе реализации](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/5378).

Но тем не менее выкладываю эту статью, так как пока неизвестно когда эта функциональность будет реализована.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что данный подход не учитывает возможность использования и передачу props через адресную строку. По этому, если у вас есть динамические роуты, то такой подход не подойдёт.

Comment: Можно добавить их автогенерацию по пропсам компонента. Нужные пропсы можно определять через соглашение по именованию, или иными способами.

Comment: Возможно, только прийдётся каждый раз генерировать, когда происходит изменение в директориях. Нужно либо watcher ставить, либо руками каждый раз вызывать (что неудобно и отнимает время).

Comment: Проще. При каждой компиляции заново делается с 0. Это копейки по времени в общем объёме